# JavaFX TableView single interval selection

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I'm developing a rich client in JavaFX using jdk 8. I have a `TableView` presenting my data and I need the user to be able to select a single interval but I haven't been able to find a way to do it.

It seems I can make the `MultipleSelectionModel` work as a single item selection by setting its selection mode to `SelectionMode.SINGLE` while if set to `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE` it allows multiple ranges (which is not what I want).

My question is: does anyone know if there is a flag somewhere or some implementation that can be used to achieve the single interval selection?
I tried to dive into the `TableView` (and related) code for some day now but I have to admit I am having a hard time following the logic.

Comment: Can't understand by single interval selection. Do you mean single cell selection or column or row ??

Comment: I am talking about rows selection and I mean what in Swing was SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION and quoting from the Swing docs "select one contiguous range of indices at a time".

Comment: tableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE); works perfectly in my case.

Comment: And can you select a contiguous range of rows?